# what is your best plot / report package to help generate repetitive reports in python ?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, report

New to python :)

I'm looking for a package in python that I need to learn. My goal is to create daily reports in a pretty format ( PDF , HTML , LaTex.. etc ) and have both charts and tables  and setup automatic schedule and send out emails to users.

I saw there are several options that  available; mathplot, scipy , .. etc.  I don't know where to start.

If you can please let me know what you are using, or what's your favorite that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you will probably want to go with matplotlib
Scipy and Numpy are just modules to help with scientific/math related problems and are used by matplotlib

Comment: @Necrolyte2 I would quibble about calling numpy/scipy 'just modules'

Comment: If you're using Python scientific libraries to create reports, you might be interested in [pythontex](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org), not 'mathplot' or any of the other libraries.  For interactive use, try [pylab](http://www.scipy.org/PyLab) within [IPython](http://ipython.org/).

[Introduction to matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/intro.html)